# VBA: Starting a loop from defined Cell

Tags: vba, range, rows

i am a beginner of VBA. I have the following Problem:

I defined a name for a cell(B4) called "Start".Now i want to count up the rows like:

```
Sub tryme()
Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To 6
    Cells(i, 1).Value = 100
Next i
```

How can i replace the value 2 with "Start"

Comment: Maybe [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57272730/11167163) I am pretty sure that it is what you asked for. Do not hesitate to **ask** me question on it or to give me some **feedbacks** if i miss understood something..

Comment: Set Range1 = Range("Start") // Range 1 is for example in B4..................... 
                                    
Set Range2 = Range(Range1 + 1) //Range2 should be B5(increment the row 1+)............But the last operation is invalid

Comment: why do you increment the row ? To count ? i don’t understand what should be Range2

Comment: i edited the question. How to make a loop:

Comment: @user3632179 Please see the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57272730/11167163)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every `Range` has a [Row property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.row) you can work with.

```
Sub tryme()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = Range("Start").Row To Range("Start").Row + 6
        Cells(i, 1).Value = 100
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I also get a downvote. I think he didn't saw that the question just been **edited**..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would use `Range(Range1, Range2).Cells.Count`. This will do the job.

**For Example :**

```
sub tryme()

' Sets Range1 as cell Start and Range2 as the cell called "End"
    Set Range1 = Range("Start")
    Set Range2 = Range("End")
' Counts how many rows are between Range1 and Range2 and calls the value MyCount
        MyCount = Range(Range1, Range2).Cells.Count
debug.print MyCount
end sub
```

After your **Edit** I propose the following code :

```
Sub tryme()

' Sets Range1 as cell Start and Range2 as the cell called "End"
Set Range1 = Range("Start")
Set Range2 = Range("End")
' Counts how many rows are between Range1 and Range2 and calls the value MyCount
MyCount = Range(Range1, Range2).Cells.Count

For i = Range1.Cells.Count To MyCount
    Cells(i, 1).Value = 100
Next
End Sub
```

To make this example work you need to set cells name as **Start** And **End** ( To do this right click on cell then click on **Define name**)  this will give you the following thing :

[image: Start]

[image]

Comment: Everything is allright but i want to start from defined cell and not from A1. look to my answer pleaase

Comment: @user3632179 If your issue is solved, May I ask you to accept this answer